# Why does my c++ compiler seem to be compiling in c

Tags: c++, c, linux, geany

I am using geany (code::blocks wouldnt run my programs) as a compiler to compile a simple c++ program with one class. I am on Linux Mint 17 on a Dell Vostro 1500. Compiling works fine with both .cpp files, but the header file gives this error:

```
gcc -Wall "Morgan.h" (in directory: /home/luke/Documents/Coding/Intro#2)
Morgan.h:5:1: error: unknown type name ‘class’
class Morgan
^
Morgan.h:6:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
{
^
Compilation failed.
```

This is the main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Morgan.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Morgan morgObject;
    morgObject.sayStuff();

   return 0;
}
```

This is the Header file (Morgan.h):

```
#ifndef MORGAN_H
#define MORGAN_H


class Morgan
{
    public:
        Morgan();
        void sayStuff();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // MORGAN_H
```

And this is the class (Morgan.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Morgan.h"
using namespace std;

Morgan::Morgan()
{
}

void Morgan::sayStuff(){
    cout << "Blah Blah Blah" << endl;
}
```

I really do not know what is going wrong, so any help would be appreciated. I copy and pasted the same code into a windows compiler and it worked fine, so it might just be the linux.

also when I run the main.cpp this is what shows:
"./geany_run_script.sh: 5: ./geany_run_script.sh: ./main: not found"

Comment: Well, you're using gcc which is a C compiler. Use g++.

Comment: Also, why are you compiling `Morgan.h` instead of `main.cpp` and `Morgan.cpp`?

Comment: If i understand right, you use Geany's compile command to compile the code. If it's the case, then you might want to go change the build commands in Geany and set them to use g++ in the way used in the answers given so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are compiling C++ code with a C compiler (GCC). The command you are looking for is `g++`. The complete command that would compile your code is:

`g++ -Wall -o run.me main.cpp Morgan.cpp`

If a file is included (In your case the `Morgan.h` file, you do not need to explicitly compile it. )

Answer (score 3):

You don't compile .h files. Try `g++ -Wall main.cpp Morgan.cpp`

Comment: @amarillo Corrected.